# How to set matplotlib to show every image of an array?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

**How to set matplotlib to show every image of an array?**

I want that everytime i click on the right arrow, it shows the next image and so on...

Is that possible?

```
width = 14
height = 14

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

data_images = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],width,height)

print "Shape " ,data_images.shape #Shape  (50000L, 14L, 14L)

plt.imshow(data_images[0])
plt.show()
```

I wanted to pass the ***"data_images"*** variable to plt.imshow and so everytime i clicked on next on the matplotlib, it would show the next image.

Comment: toggle between two images by pressing "t"  http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/pylab_examples/toggle_images.html

Comment: But i have 50 000 images. I cant keep doing im2.getVisible etc to all of them.

Comment: most important is `plt.connect(...)`

Comment: Why are my questions just down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example with `plt.connect()`.

You can change image by pressing any key.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_images = [
    [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],
    [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]],
    [[1,2,1],[2,2,2],[1,2,1]],
]

#----------------------------------

index = 0

def toggle_images(event):
    global index

    index += 1

    if index < len(data_images):
        plt.imshow(data_images[index])
        plt.draw()
    else:        
        plt.close()

#----------------------------------

plt.imshow(data_images[index])

plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_images)
plt.show()
```

Comment: NameError: global name 'index' is not defined

Comment: I need to put the whole code inside a def, but once i do that, i get that error.

Comment: `index = 0` can't be inside `def` - it have to be global variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using [`ipywidgets`](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets) within the IPython notebook. Here's an example:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import interact

images = np.random.random((500, 14, 14))

def browse_images(images):
    N = images.shape[0]
    def view_image(i=0):
        plt.imshow(images[i], cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
        plt.title('Image {0}'.format(i))
    interact(view_image, i=(0, N-1))

browse_images(images)
```

Edit: the result, in the notebook page, will look something like this:

[image]

You can press the left or right arrow to advance the slider and view the next image.

Comment: This is awesome! However i used something more simple! But thanks so much for the reply! i will keep this in mind!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a bit better in the notebook than using inline:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import interact
from IPython.display import display

images = np.random.random((500, 14, 14))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(images[0], cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
def browse_images(images):
    N = images.shape[0]
    def view_image(i=0):
        im.set_data(images[i])
        ax.set_title('Image {0}'.format(i))
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    interact(view_image, i=(0, N-1))
```

and then in the next cell

```
browse_images(images)
```

which will give you a pannable/zoom able figure.  In mpl 1.5.0 you also get the pixel values under the cursor by default.

(I tested this on tmpnb.org)